# Podio API - GET form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, podio

Looking for some help from an experienced Podio API navigator!

I'm trying to build a feature into our rails app where I can pull the details of a form from Podio, so that I can then automatically generate a form in our environemnt that can post to the app.

To do that I would need to get the category and labels of the fields..

However, when you GET a form from podio, this is all it gives you for the fields:

```
  "fields": [
    {
      "field_id": foo,
      "settings": null
    },
    {
      "field_id": foo,
      "settings": null
    }
```

any thoughts on how I might use this information to get the information that I need? Can I somehow use the field_id to GET the field?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the app and the fields within it by using GET request to,

```
 /app/{app_id}/field/{field_or_external_id}
```